# errno 9 bad file descriptor when using pip or poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-poetry

One time I tried to install pygame with pip, but it doesn't find pip.

```
can't open file 'pip' [errno 2] no such file or diretory
```

when I do "**py pip install pygame**"

So I tried reinstalling python like 4 times, and tried almost all the possible installation ways but it doesn't work. So I tried installing pip manually, I tried all possible ways but have the same error:

```
[errno 9]: bad file descriptor.
```

I tried many times.

So after that I tried to install via pycharm when I try to install it shows "no package installation tools, **install**" and when I click on install, it shows the same error.

```
[errno 9]: bad file descriptor.
```

After this I tried using poetry but when I do `poetry install win10toast` it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\bin\poetry", line 16, in <module>
    from poetry.console import main
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .application import Application
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\application.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .commands.about import AboutCommand
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\commands\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .check import CheckCommand
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\console\commands\check.py", line 1, in <module>
    from poetry.factory import Factory
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\factory.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .repositories.pypi_repository import PyPiRepository
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\repositories\pypi_repository.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cachecontrol import CacheControl
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\cachecontrol\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .wrapper import CacheControl
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\cachecontrol\wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .adapter import CacheControlAdapter
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
    from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\requests\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Users\acer\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.8\requests\compat.py", line 61, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Please help, everything I do just fails and I really need it, coding on repl.it is really hard.

Comment: Firstly, `pip` should usually be ran as a standalone, no need to do `py` before hand. Secondly, try `python -m pip install -U pip` with an **administrative** console.

Comment: okay i'll try it , even ifi think i already did it

Comment: Just make sure you skip `py pip` and just do `pip` : ) Hopefully that solves the issue.

Comment: didn't work , just some errors and bad file descriptor at the end

Comment: i also tried **pip install pygame** , it doesn't work

Comment: i even tried installing pip from source , bad file descriptor

Comment: I'm almost positive you have a problem with your OS, not with pip or python. You should check your harddrive, do a system update and go through the normal debugging proceedures and try again. This is a strange issue that has to do with opening file handles on your system being broken some where. You could try to re-install Python as well, but you might end up in a limbo where you're completely out of Python and your system depends on it and you broke your entire OS. So be careful, but that might solve it. Is your disk full? *(`df -h /`)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and checked for the solution in google in fact i even visited this page too. But before few minutes I found the solution for this error. And here you go with the answer.

Just install python in any other directory(other than the c drive).
This should probably work.